# While loop only returns the timediff of the first row

Tags: php

> Code

```
$minus = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dtr");
while($minusdata = mysql_fetch_array($minus, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $time = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT time_to_sec(timediff(time_out,time_in)) as x from dtr where dtr_id = dtr_id"));
    $t = $time['x'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE dtr SET diff = '$t' WHERE dtr_id = dtr_id AND time_out != '00:00:00'");
}
```

I know it should work. Select the timediff of 2 columns in each row then update it to a `diff` column in that row. But what is happening is only the timediff of the first row is being updated to all `diff` columns instead of the timediff in each respective row.

Example: the timediff of the first row is 5 so 5 is the data being updated to all diff columns in all rows.

Comment: You shouldn't use the mysql_* family function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: This isn't going to go live so I'll just use mysql.

Comment: Can't you just do `update dtr set diff = time_to_sec(timediff(time_out,time_in))`???

Comment: Woahh. It worked!. Never thought you can do an operation after the `=`. I thought it have'd to be selected first then updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE statement that you are using in the UPDATE is dtr_id = dtr_id . That will always be true.

So, the $time SELECT statement is selecting the first row where dtr_id is dtr_id, which is the first row that it comes to.( It would be true of every row). Then it is updating every row with that information where dtr_id = dtr_id, which is every row again.

You will likely need to adjust the SELECT and UPDATE within the loop to something using "WHERE dtr_id = $minusdata['dtr_id']". That way you will only select and update the row that you are currently on in the while loop.